# Chrome long "Content Download" time on an OPTIONS request with no response body

Tags: javascript, rest, google-chrome, network-programming

I'm getting very long (4.10 seconds) "Content Download" times from an `OPTIONS` request, even though the response tab says "This request has no response data available." and the `Content-Length` is 0.  The Waiting (TTFB) time is very short.  How is this possible?

I *think* the same thing happens in Safari, although their network tools aren't as helpful, and looking in Firefox it appears to not be an issue (based on also limited experience with their dev tools).

[image: Chrome Network Request Timing Tab]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it has something to do with an Anti-Virus programm searching for malware in the Response.
Avast for example does this. And it takes very long, especially if you have big html snippets in your response.

I had this Problem and for me it helped to b64 encode the response. After that, my request was running pretty fast again.